# Anyone know a list of flash.includes? (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm looking for a list of flash.include.whatever.whatever for as3.

If no one knows a list then can someone tell me the flash.include to use for drawing rectangle with the startFill and endFill things? Thanks for any help.

I didn't find anything on either of these googling, and the place I got the code for drawing a rectangle of course didn't have the flash.includes included in the example code... is their a reason so many people do that? Any way I can get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can using a `Graphics`.

> The Graphics class contains a set of methods that you can use to
>   create a vector shape. Display objects that support drawing include
>   Sprite and Shape objects. Each of these classes includes a graphics
>   property that is a Graphics object. The following are among those
>   helper functions provided for ease of use: drawRect(),
>   drawRoundRect(), drawCircle(), and drawEllipse(). You cannot create a
>   Graphics object directly from ActionScript code. If you call new
>   Graphics(), an exception is thrown.
>
> The Graphics class is final; it cannot be subclassed.

here is a sample

```
import flash.display.*;
this.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
```

here is a [Adobe Tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dd9.html)

AS3 all display class list [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/package-detail.html)

You do not necessarily need to default AS3 include. fine compile. But include only the code you can see the hint. perhaps, CS4 after that if you use a specific class will automatically include. or ctrl+space is autocompletion.

As follows by default when you install the flash is because of the SWC path.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... think i have the graphics class in their but will check and try other stuff. Thanks

Comment: some `Displayobject` has a property graphics. Shape, DisplayObject, Sprite, MovieClip.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want a list of the packages and classes that come with AS3? That is typically called the documentation and can be found here:

- [Adobe ActionScript<sup>®</sup> 3 API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/)

For drawing a Rectangle, you can start at [`flash.display.Shape`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html). It has a [`graphics`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) object with the methods [`.beginFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginFill%28%29) and [`.endFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#endFill%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

As per I know, there is not such  a thing like `Flash.include`. May be you're trying to ask something else or may be i am still unknown about this feature.

If you found any positive thing about this, please let me know, i want to know that new thing.

Comment: Must have been something like include flash.something... sorry about that.

Comment: I think it is import flash.display.*; like something.